# FTL eval_json fails

Tags: json, freemarker

When I am trying to parse below JSON in FTL

```js
{
  "success":true,
  "timestamp":1627886463,
  "base":"Data1",
  "date":"2021-08-02",
  "values":{
    "data2":7.5,
    "data3":44,
    "data4":33
  }
}
```

and FTL is below one

```
<#assign vals = jsonData?eval_json>
```

It fails.

Any suggestions?

As requested, below is complete java code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable{
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration(new Version("2.3.31"));
        StringTemplateLoader stringLoader = new StringTemplateLoader();
        cfg.setTemplateLoader(stringLoader);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<#assign vals = '{  \"success\":true,  \"timestamp\":1627886463,  \"base\":\"Data1\",  \"date\":\"2021-08-02\",  \"values\":{    \"data2\":7.5,    \"data3\":44,    \"data4\":33  }}'?eval_json>");
        sb.append("${vals}");
        stringLoader.putTemplate("sample", sb.toString());
        Map<String, Object> input = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Template template = cfg.getTemplate("sample");
        Writer consoleWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
        template.process(input, consoleWriter);
    }
```

and error in console is as below

```
FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!):
For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), or "template output" , but this has evaluated to an extended_hash (wrapper: f.t.SimpleHash):
==> vals  [in template "sample" at line 1, column 175]

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${vals}  [in template "sample" at line 1, column 173]
----
```

Hope this additional information will be useful to help me.

Comment: Could you expand a little by explaining how it fails please?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. After assigning the variable to "vals" I am unable to access or iterate through "vals" or access any property of "vals".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `'....'?eval_json` in `vals` is a [hash](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_direct_hash) containing the values from your json.

You can't evaluate a hash directly using `${...}`, but you can access each property in your hash individually.

For example:

```
<#assign vals='{  "success":true,  "timestamp":1627886463,  "base":"Data1",  "date":"2021-08-02",  "values":{    "data2":7.5,    "data3":44,    "data4":33  }}'?eval_json>
${vals.base}
${vals.date}
${vals.values.data2}
```

will output

```
Data1
2021-08-02
7.5
```